# js regexp mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following HTML code and am trying to get data using RegExp.
This does not work in mobile browsers.

var JSON:

```
 <div class="comment_item right">
<div class="comment_author_wrap">
    <div class="comment_author">
    </div>
</div>
    <p mid="1369">fdsfds
    </p>
```

Variable json is the response from the server.

Regexp:

```
 msg = json;
 var regexp = /<p(.*?)<\/p>/gms;
 result = msg.match(regexp);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '`s`' modifier is not supported by many browsers!

I suggest you change your regex to:

```
/<p[\s\S]*?</p>/g
```

That should work in all browsers.

What it does: It starts by matching '`<p`', then it matches any characters (including newline) any number of times until the string '`</p>`' occurs.